# can d3js stack layout function v4 support minPointLength from highcharts for zero value?

Tags: d3.js, highcharts

Can D3Js V4 support something similar with minPointLength from highcharts?
The requirement is: when the bar chart height is 0, we should take consider into this and give a minimized value, say, 1px, for example.
Currently, zero value will cause the bar chart is 0 and no visual feedback.
It is not my expectation?

Thanks~!